# From LINQ to SQL to Entity Framework, what features do you want?

Tags: linq-to-sql, entity-framework

If you're going to be moving from LINQ to SQL to the Entity Framework what features do you most want to see move along with it?  What features do you think are requirements to move existing projects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. True Persistence Ignorance.
2. Complete POCO Support.
3. No Magic String.

Answer (score 0):

Something along the lines of NHibernate when used with Fluent NHibernate that has full LINQ support.

NHibernate is the best ORM at the moment in my opinion. The only way it could be beaten as it stands is full LINQ support. NHibernate doesn't have that at the moment - only basic support - and LINQ syntax is much more appealing and natural than the options NHibernate gives you.